# How to Concatenate two list into a new list in python

Tags: python, list, automation

```
adj = ["red", "big", "tasty"]
fruits = ["apple", "banana", "cherry"]


for x in adj:
  for y in fruits:
    print(x, y)
```

I need to get the list as separate dynamically new list 1: ["red", "apple"] new list 2: ["big", "banana"] new list 3: ["tasty", "cherry"]. One problem here is list size will changed (adj,fruits)

Answer (score 0):

Try the following list comprehensions

```
combined_list_of_lists = [list(l) for l in zip(adj, fruits)]
```

Comment: It was created in single list. I need separate list dynamically based on input list size like list1 list2 and list 3

Comment: @mahendra, you can access these lists using index as `combined_list_of_lists[0], combined_list_of_lists[1], combined_list_of_lists[2]` and can assign them any name as ` list1 = combined_list_of_lists[0]` and so on